# How do I make an iOS app support iPhone 6, without supporting iPhone 5S?

Tags: ios

I want to support iPhone 6/6+, but not iPhone 5S. I know that I can use screen size to detect an iPhone 5S, but I don't want iPhone 5S users to be able to download the app in the first place. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6):

Apple will only allow you to restrict apps in the App Store by iOS version. If you create an app that doesn’t work on a device that supports the OS, from my experience Apple may give you trouble with publishing it to the App Store.